What does it mean when the laws say that a forcing 1NT response cannot guarantee invitational values?
"Invitational" usually means 10-12 high card points. A forcing 1NT response typically has a range of 6-12 points.
I consider it unwise to bid a forcing 1NT with only 6-7 points unless I have four good hearts over a 1 spade bid. Does the rule mean that "some" of my responses have to be in the 8-9 point range so that I don't "guarantee" the 10-12 point invitational range when I bid a forcing 1NT?

Please note that almost no events are played under the Basic chart.

What do you do when you hold xx AQxxx xxxx xx and partner opens 1S?

@AlexanderWoo: I bid 1NT reluctantly because of the fifth heart and because AQ is 1.5 quick tricks. But I pass xx AQxx xxxx xxx or xx AJxxx Jxxx xx  or xx KQxxx Jxxx xx. I would bid with xx KQJxx xxxx xx, because the KQJ sequence is worth 7.5 in my book., even more than xx AQxxx xxxx xx

If you pass xx AJxxx xxxx xx, you're missing game opposite AKxxx KQxx x Axx, a very good opening hand but not nearly a maximum 1S opening.

@AlexanderWoo: Maybe I should give more leeway when the suit in question is hearts. But I would never consider forcing 1NT with  xx xx AJxxx xxxx, and probably not with  xx xx AJxxx Qxxx that is, when the suit(s) in question are minors. ,

and now you're missing a slam when partner has AKxxx x Kx AKxxx (though admittedly the one of the opponents might come in given they have 10 hearts between them)

You are referring not to the laws, but to the ACBL's convention charts, which govern the conventions that are legal to play in ACBL-sanctioned events. In the Basic chart, which is designed for events with very inexperienced players, any bidding agreement not explicitly allowed is forbidden. One allowed agreement for responses to the opening bid reads:

A Forcing 1NT response to an opening bid of 1H or 1S. 1NT cannot guarantee an Invitational or stronger hand.

In this document, "Invitational" is defined to mean "A hand sufficiently strong to indicate that partner should bid game unless partner has a minimum."
Thus, the meaning of this rule is that in events governed by the ACBL Basic Chart, an agreement about  forcing 1NT response to an opening bid must include some hands that are insufficiently strong to indicate that partner should bid game with slightly more than minimum values.
On a side note, you are wrong to shy away from a forcing 1NT response with 6-7 points. The forcing 1NT response to one of a major in 2/1 should be made with all hands that would respond 1NT in Standard American, as well as some hands that would take a stronger action in SA.

I am BARELY willing to respond 1NT with six points if it were non forcing. (Partner can pass and leave us at the one level.) I'm "out" if partner is forced to the two level. With 7, I  would bid 1NT with AKxx or AQJX in a suit, but pass if I had, say three queens and a jack.

Do your partners open a lot of balanced 10-counts? Do they open 2C with 19-counts? With Qxx xx Axxx xxxx, passing 1H is losing bridge. You'll probably end up in 2C or 2D across from a minimum, but when partner holds KJx AKQxxx x AQx, aren't you sad to be in 1H instead of 4H?

If I were your partner, I would open 2 clubs with KJx AKQxxx x AQx. (Eight playing tricks that could get to 10 with the right three points (Q of spades and J of clubs) from responder). I am also experimenting with an all-purpose 2NT bid for that hand to pull in the 5 and 6 pointers. My partners open a lot of UNBALANCED 10 pointers.

So you stretch to pass with perfectly serviceable minimum responding hands, and counteract this effect by stretching to open 2C with perfectly serviceable 1H openers. I think you fear 18-point 2-level contracts too much, and don't bid slam aggressively enough after 2C openers.

One of the downsides to passing is that you encourage the opponents to come in, and now they find their fit and get their +110 rather than +100 or -50 instead of -80, or even their +110 instead of -110.

@ruds: I don't consider KJx AKQxxx x AQx, a 19 point hand. More like 23 points, after counting 2 extra points for the sixth heart, and another 2 points for the minor suit singleton, and worth a 2 club opener. Contrast this with KJx AKQxx xx AQx (five hearts and two diamonds), which I do consider 19 points (maybe 20 counting 1 point ofr the diamond doubleton.

I mean, you can do that if you want. It's not against the laws of bridge, although the hand doesn't qualify as Very Strong in the ACBL convention charts. I just think it's unwise. It's a 6331 pattern, not some exotic distributional freak. It's almost half the deck in terms of points, and it has the expected 2 aces and 2 kings you would get with half the deck. The honor structure is good, and it would be reasonable to treat it as a bit stronger than 19, but I think 23 is way overstating the strength.

I would consider 2C on Axx AKQxxx x AQx, but not KJx AKQxxx x AQx.  The first is 8.5 tricks assuming hearts split and you can get to dummy; the second is 8 (7 and 2 halves) and even then that requires 2 dummy entries.  Joe Grue did open 2C two days ago on 17 hcp, but that was a solid 9 tricks: https://vugraph.lovebridge.com/screen/usbc/436932?screen=replay&ns=439916&board=47&round=4

(cont) If you opened 2C on KJx AKQxxx x AQx, I doubt you'd be happy with partner driving to slam with Qxxx x AJxx Kxxx as Brad Moss did with an equivalent hand, though Axx AKQxxx x AQx isn't much better for slam opposite that.

The seventh spade that Joe held makes the suit much more likely to run (in addition to representing an extra trick). Two outside aces is much better than an A and a KJ, as you point out. That hand is considerably closer to an "exotic distributional freak". Good find!

@ruds, two comments.  1: "not Very Strong" for 2C only an issue on Basic/+ (not allowed).  Legal (and Alertable) on Open+.  2. Tom's hand is arguably Very Strong (5 controls and 8.5+ tricks with even breaks).  It's certainly better than the "overstrength preempts" that are the reason for 1.  I think as well as the constructive issues, he'll be very happy when it goes 2C-(2S)-p (GF)-(4S) (or 3D-5D, more likely). I have been less enamoured of "upgrading into strong bid" as days go by.

The reason why this is not allowed on the Basic charts is that it allows responders 2/1s to be non-forcing - not just "not GF", but passable.  1NT is bid with any invitational or better hand, the responses are based on it guaranteeing invitational values (we're forced to 2NT or suit agreement at the 3 level, so lots of room to, usually artificially, show hands), and 1♥-p-2♦ is "6-9, to play opposite a minimum with some diamonds".
It is believed by the (ACBL) Competition and Conventions Committee that systems with that style are so unusual and so different in thinking patterns that they would gain against newer players simply by confusion, not by being better, and we don't want to confuse newer players.  Play in the open, play on the Open Chart (or even Basic+, effectively "not Gold Rush or I/N"), and we consider you good enough that you will be able to resolve that confusion (in time, at least).
As to why for 40 years it was disallowed on the General Convention Chart (that 90+% of games were run under) - well, that's another story.  One I think all the people involved in now are dead or at least no longer playing bridge.  One I won't go into here.  If you care, start your investigation with "breakthrough system bridge".
